# Jquery Validator Add Method validation for checkbox

Tags: javascript, jquery

How to add the function like this into jQuery.validator.addMethod :

```
if (theForm.chk_ccd.checked            &&
   (! theForm.chk_ccd_pos [0].checked) &&
   (! theForm.chk_ccd_pos [1].checked) &&
   (! theForm.chk_ccd_pos [2].checked))
{
  window.alert ('Please select data from the \"CCD Position\" field.');
  theForm.chk_ccd_pos [0].focus ();
  return;
}
```

and the validate function here :

```
function ActionAdd (theForm)
    {
        $("#form").validate
        ({
            rules:
            {
                de_no: "required",
                de_name: "required",
                product_name: "required",
                plabel_no: "required",
            },
            messages:
            {
                de_no: "<div class='error'>Please provide Part No.</div>",
                de_name: "<div class='error'>Please provide Model Name</div>",
                product_name: "<div class='error'>Please provide Product Name</div>",
                plabel_no: "<div class='error'>Please provide Part No. (Pack Label)</div>",
            }
        });
    }
```

Anyone please help, I have stuck with that case.
Thanks

Answer (score -1):

[Here's a sample](http://jsfiddle.net/5R3dR/)

```
<form id="myForm" action="">
<br />check 1?
<input type="checkbox" id="check0" name="check0" class="chkgroup"/>
<br />check 2?
<input type="checkbox" id="check1" name="check1" class="chkgroup"/>
<br />check 3?
<input type="checkbox" id="check2" name="check2" class="chkgroup"/>
<br />
<input type="submit" />
```

```
$(function () {
    jQuery.validator.addMethod("checkboxCheck", function(value, element,params) {
            return $(params[0]+':checked').length > 0;
    });
    $("#myForm").validate({

        rules: {
            check0:{
                checkboxCheck:['.chkgroup'],
            },
        },
        messages: {
            check0:{
                checkboxCheck: "check your checkbox",
            },
        },
        submitHandler: function(form) {
            // ajax goes here
            alert("valid form");
            return false;
        }
    });

});
```